# Ruby on rails action mailer sending mails from previous setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Hi i have an app in which i am using action mailer to send the mail ,

i am drowned in this really weird issue

the issue is i set up the mail setting in the development and the production environment to send the mails from the gmail domain . that worked perfectly but then i decided to send emails from my domain 
which i purchased from the go daddy

this is my code

**development.rb**

```
  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtpout.secureserver.net",
      :port                 => 80,
      :domain               => "jobzgo.com",
      :user_name            => 'mydomainemailid',
      :password             => 'mydomainpasswrd',
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

in controller

```
 def create
  @form = Form.create(form_params)
    if @form.save
      FormMailer.registration_mail(@form).deliver
      redirect_to forms_path
    end
  end
```

i dont know how but i am still receiving the mails from gmail domain and the old gmail id i provided as the sender

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening along with the solution
wud be really a great help stuck in this issue

Comment: did you restart your server ?

Comment: yes the first thing i did this only

Comment: i am using thin as the server

Comment: maybe you gmail settings are in some initializer file overriding the new one...

Comment: can you please tell me from where i can see this issue

Comment: You have to look into the initializers (`config/initializers`).

Comment: Do you have the SMTP settings in your `test` or `development` environment set?

Comment: there are 8 files assets , backtrace_silencer, cookies_serializers, inflections, mime_types, session_store, wrap_parameters and no file giving any clue

Comment: @Tobias - i am having these setting in development and production environment , also when i deployed the app on heroku it is still sending from gmail

Comment: And have you updated the settings of both of these files or just the `development.rb`?

Comment: Hmm.. Is your Git directory up-to-date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96493/discussion-between-user4965201-and-tobias).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set the `default from:` to your Gmail address in your `app/mailers/application_mailer.rb`.

BTW I would highly recommend you to move credentials out of the codebase into the environment variables.